# Reverse Engineering C++ code using "Enterprise Architect"

Tags: c++, uml, reverse-engineering

It is again a sort of "how to do it properly" question. Sorry if someone is annoyed.

I've got to understand ca 150 TLOCs of C/C++ mixture. I've imported the code in UML-Tool "Enterprise Architect" and got a messy chart. Many Structs and Enums had anonymous names because of this C-ish constructs: `typedef struct/enum {...} MyType;`

In second run I've converted  it to C++ form: `struct/enum  MyType{...};` but got a bunch of unrelated structs. Unfortunately, Enterprise Architect doesn't resolve typedefs. e.g. no relations between A, B and C were recognized:

```
struct A;
struct B;
typedef A *PtrA;
typedef List<B> BList;
struct C{ PtrA pA; BList lB; };
```

Thanks to throughout naming convention, I was able to replace all typedefs by original type like this:

```
struct C{ A pA; B lB; };
```

Now importing source-code in "Enterprise Architect" gave a nice diagram with all relations. 
Of cause, the code doesn't compile, and is not the same. All changes in code require an annoying conversion for making this "pseudo" code understandable by EA again. Therefore my questions:

1. Is there any possibility to teach EA
   recognizing the original types?
2. Do other UML-Tools recognize the types
   (and create relations between them)
   more robust?

Thank you very much for any advice!
Valentin Heinitz

Comment: You have more than one problem here. EA appears to be failing for typedefs, but even if you find a workaround for that, you will find that it does not know (at rev 8.0) about a relationship between B and List<B>, which makes reverse engineering code which makes much use of the STL a pain. Sparx is aware of the problem and have reported to my employers that they are 'working on it'.

Comment: I have also found that I generally have to change the type of the associations that EA creates - it always seems to create general associations between classes, which I have to manually change to aggregations or compositions as appropriate. I also usually have to do a degree of manual layout. Given all this work in EA anyway, is it really worth changing your code to make the import work? couldn't you just add the missing links to the UML afterwards?

Comment: @Tony: Thank you for info. I will check a new version. Comment 2: Yes, it is worth modifying the code since there are about 100 classes and the code-modification done in VI almost automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have Enterprise Architect, and almost invariably for doing what you are attempting on a large code body I use [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) instead.  It generates both class and call graphs. Use it with [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/) and "UML-style" class diagrams, and you have a reasonably good code navigation and comprehension tool, with flexible configuration to add or exclude detail as necessary.